# PHP JSON from API Changing Position

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to get an API about movie schedule. But the json output wasn't as what I want. I want to make it sort by Theater, not sorted by movie. So, I should changing the json value position, is it possible? This the output json I got from the API

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "movie": "movie A",
            "schedule": [
                {
                    "theater": "theater A",
                    "time": [
                        "13:00",
                        "15:00",
                        "17:00",
                        "19:00",
                        "21:00"
                    ],
                    "price": "Rp.60,000"
                },
                {
                    "theater": "theater B",
                    "time": [
                        "13:00",
                        "15:00",
                        "17:00",
                        "19:00",
                        "21:00"
                    ],
                    "price": "Rp.50,000"
                }
            ]
        }
        {
            "movie": "movie B",
            "schedule": [
                {
                    "theater": "theater A",
                    "time": [
                        "13:00",
                        "15:00",
                        "17:00",
                        "19:00",
                        "21:00"
                    ],
                    "price": "Rp.60,000"
                },
                {
                    "theater": "theater B",
                    "time": [
                        "13:00",
                        "15:00",
                        "17:00",
                        "19:00",
                        "21:00"
                    ],
                    "price": "Rp.50,000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here what json that I want to have

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "theater": "theater A",
            "schedule": [
                {
                    "movie": "Movie A",
                    "time": [
                        "13:00",
                        "15:00",
                        "17:00",
                        "19:00",
                        "21:00"
                    ],
                    "price": "Rp.60,000"
                },
                {
                    "movie": "Movie B",
                    "time": [
                        "13:00",
                        "15:00",
                        "17:00",
                        "19:00",
                        "21:00"
                    ],
                    "price": "Rp.50,000"
                }
            ]
        }
        {
            "theater": "theater B",
            "schedule": [
                {
                    "movie": "Movie A",
                    "time": [
                        "13:00",
                        "15:00",
                        "17:00",
                        "19:00",
                        "21:00"
                    ],
                    "price": "Rp.60,000"
                },
                {
                    "movie": "Movie B",
                    "time": [
                        "13:00",
                        "15:00",
                        "17:00",
                        "19:00",
                        "21:00"
                    ],
                    "price": "Rp.50,000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Or maybe there is possible way to make the first output json sorted by theater. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
// JSONfrom api is stored in $apiJSON
$apiArr = json_decode($apiJSON, true);
$tmpArr = array();
foreach ($apiArr['data'] as $data) {
    $movie = $data['movie'];
    foreach ($data['schedule'] as $schedule) {
        $tmpArr[$schedule['theater']][] = array('movie'=>$movie,'time'=>$schedule['time'],'price'=>$schedule['price']);
    }
}

// Create new array structure
$newArr = array();
foreach ($tmpArr as $theater=>$movies) {
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp['theater'] = $theater;
    $tmp['schedule'] = $movies;
    $newArr['data'][] = $tmp;
}
```